# python recv losing first bytes of data

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization

I have a problem when recieving messages sent over an ssl socket. On rare occasions I lose the first few bytes of data in the message. I am pretty certain this somehow is a speed problem since it only seems to happen when 2 messages are sent in rapid succession (1-2 milliseconds apart). I am running the recieving code in a separate  thread with minimal code dumping the messages in a queue as they arrive.

```
queue = Queue()
...

def read_feed(session_key, hostname, port, ssl_socket):

''' READ whatever is coming on the stream '''
while (1):
    try:
        output = ssl_socket.recv(2048) # Message size always < 2048
    except (ConnectionResetError, OSError):
        logger.info("Connecting feed")
        try:
            ssl_socket.connect((hostname, port))
        except ValueError: # Something's wrong, disconnect and do a new round
            ssl_socket.close()
        else:
            cmd = {"cmd":"login", "args":{"session_key":session_key}}
            data = str.encode(json.dumps(cmd) + "\n")
            num_bytes = ssl_socket.send(data)
    else:
        queue.put(output)
...

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
...

t3 = threading.Thread(target=read_feed, name = 'Read Feed', args=(session_key, hostname, port, ssl_socket))
t3.start()
```

I was first suspecting that somehow the other threads running was stealing too much CPU time so that the network buffer was filled before this thread got a chance to run, but I have tried to use a multi core machine and the problem persists.

In essense this should be the only code running when I am connected?

```
while (1):
    output = ssl_socket.recv(2048) # Message size always < 2048
    queue.put(output)
```

Or am I making the wrong assumptions here? Maybe the try:/except: construct is costly, or is the queue.put method slow and I should use something else? Or maybe Python is not the right tool for the job?

Any suggestions on how to improve the code so that I don't lose those few precious first bytes?

Comment: Just a thought... are you sure you didn't receive the missing bytes in the previous read?  Sockets do not provide "message" based communication. They just transmit data, and when you read from the socket, you will receive everything that is in there. be it one message, a partial message or several messages.  If your intent is to send messages, I suggest ZeroMQ module. Easy to use and it provides a higher, message level interface.

Comment: A common socket programming mistake is to read the socket and process data, and if data seems to be erroneous, ignore it.  It can easily happen that your 1000 characters long message is only half way transmitted when you decide to read, in which case you will only receive the first half, ignore it as being too short, receive the rest and wonder where did the first half go.

Comment: Great tip, of course the data was there all the time! I have spent so much time trying to figure out what was wrong but looking in the wrong place. I thought the data went missing because the computer could not keep up. The missing data appeared at the end of the previous transmission and was thrown away when processing that, making it look like some data was lost.